# Can't Create MySQL TRIGGER when i use IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TRIGGER b_I_O AFTER UPDATE ON book
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status != OLD.status ) THEN
    INSERT INTO book_in_out (astatus, bid, time) VALUES(NEW.status, OLD.id, NOW());
END IF;
END;
```

First post here after hours of searching.

I'm trying to insert into book_in_out using trigger after updating booking table, I was able to do this but if I update `bookName` the trigger will try to run.

I only want the trigger to run only when status column changes. default value for `status` column is `NULL`

Below is the error i keep getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: The trigger looks good. Only thing you are missing is the delimiter. When do you get error ? After you write the trigger or when you update the table and trigger gets executed ?

Comment: it looks okay to me... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10a266/1 can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i really appreciate it. the trigger was created regardless of the error (i saw it in the trigger table). I am using phpMyAdmin 4.0. It ignores the trigger when is OLD.status is NULL but the issue now is that if is not NULL and the NEW.status not Null and NEW.status != OLD.status, the Insert doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER b_I_O AFTER UPDATE ON book
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status != OLD.status ) THEN
        INSERT INTO book_in_out (`astatus`, `bid`, `time`) VALUES(NEW.status, OLD.id, NOW());
    END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks KielSoft, `DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER c_attend AFTER UPDATE ON children
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status != OLD.status ) THEN
    INSERT INTO children_attendance (cid, astatus,  time) VALUES(OLD.id, NEW.status,  NOW());
END IF;
END;`  this works with no error, but the Insert Trigger doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to manually specify delimeter for your trigger so it won't be confused with semicolons used within BEGIN/END, i.e.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER b_I_O AFTER UPDATE ON book
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status != OLD.status ) THEN
    INSERT INTO book_in_out (astatus, bid, time) VALUES(NEW.status, OLD.id, NOW());
END IF;
END;//
```

Comment: The problem now is that the Insert does not work if the condition is met. Help pls. thanks

Comment: Did you set the delimeter back to; with delimiter ; command? What is your error now?

Comment: There's no error but the INSERT TRIGGER doesn't work if the conditions are met.

Comment: Are you sure that your NEW.status != OLD.status condition is met?

Comment: Thanks Niemand, It works if the OLD.status IS NOT NULL but if its NULL it doesn't insert

Comment: Well it shouldn't insert when OLD.status is null because you used "OLD.status IS NOT NULL" in your if clause. So everything is correct. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, but if OLD.status is null and NEW.status is not null it should insert which is not inserting at all. it worked if OLD.status is not null and its not empty.

Comment: in the current version you insert only when OLD.Status is NOT null. Could you post more detailed info about logic you want to execute? You can try this:
IF (OLD.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status != OLD.status) OR (OLD.status IS NULL AND NEW.status IS NOT NULL)