# MySQL Trigger Not Compiling and logic

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to implement the following trigger but I am getting a MySQL syntax error. The idea is that after each time the table is updated I want to set the updated 'valid' field to 0 if the 'banned' field has been changed to 1. Also is the logic below correct?

```
Create Trigger `customers` Before Update on `customers` for each row BEGIN
    set new.valid = 0 WHERE new.banned = 1;
END;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't Create MySQL TRIGGER when i use IS NOT NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769837/cant-create-mysql-trigger-when-i-use-is-not-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the trigger should be something as

```
delimiter //
Create Trigger `customers_update` 
Before Update on `customers` 
for each row 
BEGIN
    IF new.banned = 1 
     THEN set new.valid = 0 ;
    END IF ;
END;//
```

As you can see I have used `delimiter` in the trigger which is needed for the trigger. There is a nice explanation of this here [What does DELIMITER // do in a Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346637/what-does-delimiter-do-in-a-trigger)

Comment: You should probably also mention the reason why his trigger didn't compile (delimiters)